# Magento 1.9.2.3 to 2.0.2 migration issue

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, migration, magento-2.0.2

I am trying to migrate magento 1.9.2.3 to 2.0.2. I successfully installed both magento 1.9.2.3 and 2.0.2.

I've installed composer using `install composer: 
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`
.

Then i am tried to install Data Migration Tool via git using `php composer.phar config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool`
.

It shows this error:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content
[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool, git was not found, check that is installed and in your PATH env.
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
require [--dev][--prefer-source][--prefer-dist][--no-progress][--no-update][--update-no-dev][--update-with-dependencies][--ignore-platform-reqs][--sort-packages][-o|--optimize-autoloader][-a|--classmap-authoritative][--][<packages>]..
```

What was wrong and how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is that git is not installed on your machine

To install it I reckon you should follow the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)

Answer (score 0):

First install git using this command,

- `sudo apt install git-all`

Now to install Data Migration Tool using this command,

```
- composer update
- composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
- composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.0.2
- php bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.4/config.xml
- php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.4/config.xml
```

In above code, Please replace 1.9.2.4 with your Magento1 version.

After completed your migration process, execute this command,

```
- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Replace 1.9.2.4 with your Magento1 version. this is right **@Saravanam**